# Configure $ngResource: POST

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource

I´m a newbie using a $resource but I have this issue, I can´t POST my info and the response is "OPTIONS" and "404".

Could tell me what is wrong? Thanks.

```
//Model Side
app.factory("Contact", function ($resource) { //$resource(url,[paramDefaults], [actions],  options);
    return $resource(
            api_url + "/client/:idClient/contact/:idContact",
        { idClient: '@idClient', idContact: '@idContact'},
       {
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'newContact': {method: 'POST',params: {idClient: '@idClient'}},
        'getContact':{method: 'GET', isArray: false}
        }
    );
});

//Controller Side 
var contact = {"name":"mary", "lastname":"kurry","phone":"1234324234"}; 
Contact.newContact({'idClient':idClient}, contact);
```

Comment: Sounds like you're making a cross domain call but the API doesn't support CORS.

Comment: I've already activated CORS and I've made other simple requests.

Comment: @AnthonyChu I do it a $http post, and it response "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.49:9005' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. "

Comment: @AnthonyChu I  checked my entire app and the problem are in my app, because i wrote in GO or Golang and I put the header but doesn't work.
I resolved with a proxie server.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple way:

```
Contact contact = {"name":"mary", "lastname":"kurry","phone":"1234324234"};
contact.$newContact({'idClient':idClient});
```

See more at this example:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

```
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
 {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
  charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
 });

// We can retrieve a collection from the server
var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
  // GET: /user/123/card
  // server returns: [ {id:456, number:'1234', name:'Smith'} ];

  var card = cards[0];
  // each item is an instance of CreditCard
  expect(card instanceof CreditCard).toEqual(true);
  card.name = "J. Smith";
  // non GET methods are mapped onto the instances
  card.$save();
  // POST: /user/123/card/456 {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
  // server returns: {id:456, number:'1234', name: 'J. Smith'};

  // our custom method is mapped as well.
  card.$charge({amount:9.99});
  // POST: /user/123/card/456?amount=9.99&charge=true {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
});
```